# Mountain pass theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

Let $I$ be a real functional over a Hilbert space $H$, satisfying all the conditions in the Mountain pass (M-P) theorem. My question is, can the assumption in the M-P theorem that $I[v]\leq 0$ for a $v$ such that $||v||=r$ be replaced by simply $I[v]=0$?. I think the $<$ zero is redundant.

Comment: that should be a consequence of the intermediate value theorem

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you explain it a bit more?...@sanjab...

Comment: actually I prefer someone else would give a more concrete answer. By the intermediate value theorem, suppose that $I[v] < 0$ for some $\|v\| > r$, and $I[v] \geq a$ for all $\|v\| = r$ then there is a $\|v_0\| > r$ with $I[v_0]=0$...

Comment: by the way, I think in your question you mean $\|v\| > r$?